# No route matches when passing arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

1- I want to pass the project ID to retrieve the files that are linked to that project, but I can't pass arguments, it says :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"retrieveFiles", :id=>8}
```

2- Idearly I would like to stay on the same html page, and simply populate a Text Area for instance..

any ideas ? :)
Thanks

Routes.rb

```
   get 'Projects/RetrieveFiles/:id'
```

Projects_Controller

```
def retrieveFiles
@files = Project.find(params[:id]).pfiles

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @files }
  end
 end
```

show.rb

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %> |
<%= link_to 'RetriveFiles', :controller => 'projects', :action => 'retrieveFiles' , :id    => @project.id %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think routes are case sensative, try

```
get 'projects/retrievefiles/:id'
```

Comment: Right, I didn't have enough rep to comment on his post.  So in the spirit of helping others I used the resources this site allowed me.  I have the rep now so it won't be a problem.